# Visual Studio 2015 msvcp120.dll is missing

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, visual-studio-2015

I have created an empty Project in Visual Studio 2015.
When I try to run the Debugger an Error Message says, that the msvcp120.dll is missing. I already read, that the redistributable have to be installed for 32Bit and 64Bit. So I installed them or re-installed them. But I still get these Error. The msvcp120.dll is in the system32 directory.
Do I have to link it somewhere in VS?

EDIT: I forgot to say: I work with OpenCV 3.0
[image]

Comment: Something doesn't sound correct here. VS2015 would be using the msvcp140.dll by default, the msvcp120.dll is from the 2013 runtime. Are you sure you're creating an empty project without modifications and you've installed the correct components?

And have you installed the correct runtime (2013, not 2015)?

Comment: It doesn't make much sense to debug an empty project, surely you wrote some code.  We can't see it.  Just never use the Empty Project template to get started.  Always start with Win32 > Win32 Console Application.  And be sure that "hello world" works.  And if it doesn't then you need to get the VS install fixed.

Comment: I found out whats the Problem. As I said in the "EDIT" I worked with OpenCV 3.0 (for the first time). And the problem is: OpenCV 3.0 doesn't work with VS2015. So I downloaded OpenCV 3.1 and now it works.